# How can I get the configuration settings for an ASP Classic / ASP.NET website from within an .NET dll registered in the GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, asp-classic, gac

Why do I need to do this?

I help to maintain a website written in both ASP Classic and ASP.NET which we would eventually like to rewrite as .NET only.

We are constantly adding new features, and as a result the ASP Classic side of the system continues to grow. To combat this I am trying to add any new functionality to the ASP Classic side to a .NET class library loaded into the GAC. This is then called as a COM object by the ASP Classic side of the system.

This seems to work fine so far but I need access information such as the connection strings and various other app settings from within the class library. As this information is already contained in the global.asa / web.config for the site, it seems like that is the most sensible place to get it from rather than creating another point of maintenance somewhere.

As I have little experience working in the context of the GAC, I am at a bit of a loss as to how best to get this info. I would happily settle for an answer which would enable me to identify the webroot path of the calling application as if there is no better solution, I could get the info with `System.IO`.

Thanks very much indeed for your time.

Comment: Thanks marc_s for your edits.